# Series representation of hypergeometric function reciprocal?

Tags: power-series, hypergeometric-function

Basically, can you represent $\dfrac{1}{_2F_1(a,b;c;z)}$ as some kind of power series?

EDIT: This question came from something I was doing with generating functions were

$\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} f_ix^i = 1 - \dfrac{1}{\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} u_ix^i}$

Based on the value of $u_i$ (which I know) I get the denominator portion to be $_2F_1(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};1;x)$ but since I need to find some relationship between $f_i$ and the hypergeometric function's coefficients I need to represent the first expression as a power series. I'm not very familiar with the manipulation of power series and whatnot but I understand how they work and basic addition/multiplication using them.

I tried just taking a derivative of both sides but it doesn't really work that well because I still end up with stuff in the denominator. I've been told that the expansion is possible but after searching around the Internet I haven't really found anything conclusive -- or my current knowledge is missing some pieces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume $c$ is not a non-positive integer (which would cause the hypergeometric function to be undefined).  The series defining $f(z) = {}_{2}F_1(a,b;c;z)$ converges for $|z| < 1$ to an analytic function, with value $1$ at $0$, so its reciprocal is analytic in some neighbourhood of $0$.  If 
$f(z) = 1 + \sum_{j=1}^\infty c_j z^j$, then 
$1/f(z) = 1 + \sum_{j=1}^\infty d_j z_j$ with $d_1 = -c_1$ and 
$$d_n = -c_n - \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} c_j d_{n-j} \ \text{for} \ n \ge 2$$

Comment: In the $f(z) = 1 + \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} c_j z^j$ equation you give I'm assuming the c doesn't have to do with the c in the hypergeometric function?

Comment: Correct.  I probably should have used a different letter.

Comment: Could you tell me where I could read more about this? How did you come to the conclusion you came to here?

Comment: Is this also a hypergeometric function?

Comment: @user48672 No, except for some very special cases, such as ${}_2F_1(a,b;a;x) = 1/{}_2F_1(-b,c;c;x)$.